# Default values and its generalization

Tags: macros

Dear old friend StackOverflow,

I follow [this tutorial](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/newcomopt.html) on how to setup optional command values: In a multiple-value configuration like `\newcommand{\price}[2][42]{\pounds #2 excl VAT @ #1\%}`, the command output `\price{100}` gives output equal to `\price[42]{100}`.

My question goes in the generalization direction: there are optional and mandatory arguments in a command. It means, we may organize them as TWO sets, which the former is mandatory and the latter is optional. In case none of the optional are fulfilled, each default value must supply its matter.

My particular case is less stressful: provide a command `\documentpath` which gives a
custom user-defined string:

1. `\documentpath{Luke Skywalker}` ==> `Luke Skywalker`
2. `\documentpath` ==> `Darth Vader`

Comment: optional arguments should be in `[]` not `{}` so `\documentpath[Luke Skywalker]`

Comment: `\newcommand\documentpath[1][Darth Vader]{#1}`

Comment: Oooh my goodness! I am in presence of a Latex celebrity! :-X Do you know Larry Lamport in person?

Comment: Please, press the "star" button on this repository https://github.com/alloyha/TheXis if you have a Github account. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is optional so should use `[]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\documentpath[1][Darth Vader]{#1}

\begin{document}


1:    \documentpath[Luke Skywalker]

2:    \documentpath

\end{document}
```

---

Or a version saving an internal variable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\newcommand\documentpath[1][Darth Vader]{#1}
\newcommand\savedpath{NOT SET}
\newcommand\documentpath[1][Darth Vader]{\def\savedpath{#1}}
\begin{document}


0: The saved path is \savedpath

1:  \documentpath[Luke Skywalker]%
    The saved path is \savedpath

2:  \documentpath
    The saved path is \savedpath

\end{document}
```

Comment: The question has an answer already. However, my latex class may require some further investigation: in my use case, I need either a custom or a default string. In both cases, they must be stored somehow, like a variable. This variable-like command, in our case `\documentpath`, corresponds to custom or default value in the class context given by user during the document preamble, for example, by `\documentpath[path_to_file]`.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto perhaps you really want `\newcommand\documentpath[1][Darth Vader]{\def\foo{#1}}` so the string is saved in `\foo` rather than directly typeset

Comment: May you be kinder (no german pun intended) and rephrase your answer in this regard?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto done

Comment: You deserve the place you owe in Oxford. :-)